# Fetch data from a JSON File

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have this JSON file :

```
[{"Id":"1","name":"Bryan"}]
```

But I don't know how to achieve this in Android. I've tried this:

```
    val url = "url of my website"
```

Then this:

```
var json=JSONObject(values[1])
                val id = json.getJSONArray("Id")
                val name = json.getJSONObject("name")
                var.text = name
```

But it does not work. I would like to know where's the error.

Comment: Some more information would be nice. How are you loading / assigning the "values" collection, and what incorrect output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You already have your object with you in your **json** object, `id` and `name` are not JSONobjects, they are inside your `json` object.
To retrieve them do this:

```
var json=JSONObject(values[1])
val id = json.getString("Id")
val name = json.getString("name")
var.text = name
```

Answer (score 0):

[{"Id":"1","name":"Bryan"}]  this is a json array

so use the following to extract

I assume

```
String response= "[{"Id":"1","name":"Bryan"}]";

JSONArray jarray= new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){

  JSONObject object= jarray.getJsonObject(i);
  int id=object.getString("Id");
  String name=object.getString("name);

}
```

If the array size is more than one , you can initialise an arraylist with some object

Hope it helps you